# Parse CSS file when browser load

Tags: css, regex, apache, .htaccess

So I've been playing around with [`htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) for Windows Apache, and I wanted to do some minimal parsing of CSS files when it's requested (somewhat like LESS/SASS but with only variables since I don't want to use lots of server resources for every CSS load.)

I tried changing this line in my file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

To:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(ico,js,jpg,gif,png)$
```

But that's making all my other files get redirected through my PHP framework, making the output of the document end up being a HTML document, and throws a bunch of exceptions in the **Chrome Dev Tools**, am I writing this wrong?

The way this is meant to work is `Request CSS file from index load` **>** `PHP picks it up in framework router` **>** `file_get_contents File and parse` **>** `Output file after parse & exit`

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the redirect to happen for CSS files, you can have `RewriteRule` apply only when there is a .css extension:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.)css$ $1php
```

Comment: For the redirect, what file is it being redirected to?

Comment: It should redirect to the same path with the extension changed from .css to .php.